# Installing pyobdc

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install pyodbc using pip3 but getting the below error:

```
[hvr@07EUW1HVRHAP02A ~]$ pip3 install pyodbc
Collecting pyodbc
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/81/0d/bb08bb16c97765244791c73e49de9fd4c24bb3ef00313aed82e5640dee5d/pyodbc-4.0.30
.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: pyodbc
  Running setup.py install for pyodbc ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-dp0ls1b2/pyodbc/setup.py'
;f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" insta
ll --record /tmp/pip-0dv3z9sq-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'pyodbc' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src
    gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-s
trong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DPYODBC_VERSION=4.0.30 -I/
usr/include/python3.6m -c src/buffer.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src/buffer.o -Wno-write-strings -DHAVE_UNISTD_H -DHAVE_PWD_H -D
HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H -DHAVE_LONG_LONG -DSIZEOF_LONG_INT=8 -I/usr/include
    In file included from src/buffer.cpp:12:0:
    src/pyodbc.h:56:17: fatal error: sql.h: No such file or directory
     #include <sql.h>
                     ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
   
    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-dp0ls1b2/pyodbc/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'op
en', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-0dv
3z9sq-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-dp0ls1b2/pyod
bc/
```

Comment: check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31353137/sql-h-not-found-when-installing-pyodbc-on-heroku - try to install ```unixodbc unixodbc-dev``` to get the missing header files...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue can be address by first installing [ODBC libraries for UNIX](https://packages.debian.org/sid/unixodbc-dev) by running following commands:

> :~$ sudo apt install unixodbc-dev

> :~$ pip install pyodbc

Comment: I have already installed unixodbc-dev in my server but still same error. I'm using pip3 install pyodbc and not pip. Any other packages to be installed or module paths to be modified